# Website Username Check

Tags: php

I want to create a function that takes a URL parameter and a username parameter that goes to that url, enters the username and if the page says that the username doesn't exist(error) it will return false, otherwise it will return true. So I tried and I did something a little like this, but it didnt work.

```
function ($url, $username) {
    $main = file_get_contents($url.$username);
    if (@$main) { return false; }
    else { return true; }
}
```

So if you have any ideas on how to make this idea actually work please help me

Comment: If you want to suppress the error, do this: `@file_get_contents(...)` But you might do better to test it with `file_exists`, especially since you seem not to be doing anything with the contents. Also, are you sure the value of `$url.$username` is structured correctly?

Comment: Assuming you have a database... Why not query it?

Comment: @Jeffman I had it structed perfectly, thats just a rough sketch of what I had earlier, I scrapped the code about 15 minutes ago, shouldn't of, but I did. And Lawrence Cherone I want to check sites like YouTube, Facebook, Wordpress, etc, not my own site.

Comment: Have you looked into the Youtube, facebook, or twitter dev tools? They all have good documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
$site = 'https://twitter.com/';
$username = 'SteveMartinToGo';
$url = $site.$username;

function urlExists($url=NULL) {
    if($url == NULL) return false;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 400){
        return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}

if(urlExists($url)) {
    echo 'url exists';
} else {
    echo 'url does not exist';
}
```

The problem with this is that some sites (like Facebook) will return a 200 instead of a 404, so the URL will show as existing even though it's not. Also, I got this function from someplace else (can't remember where though) so I don't want to take credit for that code. hope it helps...

Edit: updated because of fred-ii's eagle eye and suggestions. :)

Comment: I think this `$url = $site.username;` should be `$url = $site.$username;` because otherwise, it will render/echo as `http://www.twitter.com/username` ;-)

Comment: Plus, since Twitter runs off of straight `http://` and not `www`, will always show any (non-existing) name as existing. Using `$site = 'http://twitter.com/';` will fix that and "work" ;-) (tested)

Comment: Thanks for the save - yet again. :)

Comment: You're welcome Tim. You have some good ideas, that's why I do it ;-)

Comment: Don't know why I had www in there - I don't like www and shy away from that as often as possible. thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome (again, lol) - I thought earlier that it needed to be `https`, since Twitter runs off of `https://twitter.com`, but it did not make a difference. It works with or without the `https`.

Comment: You could even add `echo "\n"; echo $url; echo "\n"; echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Go there now';` after `echo 'url exists';` if found for added interaction.

Comment: Yep! I'm actually building an app that does exactly this (and auto-builds the links), using urls that also have subdomains. it's a pain in the ass because of the way the sites handle their 404s.

Comment: Now it couldn't be THAT bad if it's a pain in the "ass". A pain in the "neck", now THAT hurts even more, and I know how both of those feel! lol But seriously, yeah I can imagine how it can be a pain in "general". I've never built "APPS" as per se, am just getting familiarized with MySQLi. PDO doesn't work on my server, so sticking with what I know best for now, backend and graphics. (circa 1985)

Comment: Ha! Backend and graphics too - building since 1996. Try esSQL for an awesome db class that uses mysqli: https://github.com/jv2222/ezSQL

Comment: Actually, you know what I said about the `https`? Well I take it back LOL! You need it to be `https`, I just ran another test with some added functionality and it showed (a made-up name) as being existing. When I changed it to `https`, the made-up name was non-existant.

Comment: Thanks for the link Tim, I'll surely download it and study it.

Comment: Pet peeve: you don't need a default parameter just because one of your parameters might be `null`. The `=NULL` in `function urlExists($url=NULL)` means you can run `urlExists()`, not passing in an argument, and it will return `false`, but this would never ever be useful. If you happen to call `urlExists($some_variable_that_is_null)`, you don't need an `=NULL` in the function definition, because something is still being passed in as `$url`, it just happens to `== null`.

Comment: @IMSoP If I understand correctly, if you leave out `$url=NULL` in `function urlExists($url=NULL)`, then from what I tested, if a username "exists", it will return false, therefore `$url=NULL` is needed inside the function. I tested this both ways myself.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, the `=null` is a default parameter value, used *only* if you call the function *without any parameters*, i.e. `urlExists()`. You could equally write `function urlExists($url='http://example.com')` or `function urlExists($url='OMGWTF')`, and calling it as `urlExists(null)` (or with some variable which was `null`) would still make `$url` have the value `null` inside the function. It is up to the *body* of the function to detect that `null` and behave appropriately, as you do with the line `if($url == NULL) return false;`.

Comment: @IMSoP Ok I understand. Thanks for the added explanation, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to have the actual structure of the url. You can make a print and view the source code (HTML) if there is no special characters in the URL can be masked.